# how to disable screenshot in iOS app?

Tags: ios, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling iPhone screenshot feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586592/disabling-iphone-screenshot-feature)

I want to stop users from taking screenshots of my app since it will contain copyrighted materials (pictures and information).

How can this be done in iOS? (I just want to stop screenshots being taken from the same iPhone)

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350145/circumvent-screenshot-for-ios-4

Comment: No it's not.  That question asks about how to blank the screen before the auto-screenshot gets taken.  This one is how to prevent the power-home combination from causing a screenshot.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586592/disabling-iphone-screenshot-feature