# iOS Hiding Elements on Screenshot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I've extensively searched the web, and everything I've found suggests that I can use 'applicationDidEnterBackground' to detect that a screenshot is about to be taken, hide the relevant controls, and then show them again in 'applicationWillEnterForeground'.

[Circumvent screenshot for iOS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350145/circumvent-screenshot-for-ios-4)

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this message to be sent to my app when I take a screenshot on the device.  I've even created a brand new template app, and tried that, and they are still not sent.

The only thing I can think of is that I'm running iOS 5.0.1 on my device, and all of the web pages I've found have referred to iOS 4.

Can anyone verify they have it working on iOS 5, and if so, what do I need to do to get it working in my app?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The srceenshot talked about in the thread you mentioned is the one used when app is send to the background when the user presses the home button. 
It is the screen that the user will see when you start the app when it is already running.

You arre talking about the screenshot when the user is pressing the home and power button are pressed at the same time.

The screenshot with this methods (home + power button) can't be detected by my knowledge.