# Delete Image from iPhone Photo Library with Undocumented iOS API's?

Tags: ios, screenshot, alassetslibrary, undocumented-behavior

i am creating an app for iOS devices for **my client who will use enterprise distribution but without configuration utility so we wont have to go through Apple who will restrict use of undocumented API's**. I need to **disable the screenshot functionality** of iOS device. But since i cant find it anywhere what api or method to use i am shifting to the idea of **deleting the latest image from iPhone Photo Library once screenshot is taken** maybe through some asset library undocumented version.

It could have done easily with configuration utility but my client wont agree on this as it will disable entire device screenshot taking capability and not only of the app.

I understand,if **we dont have to go to apple store for review** so there must be way to do it.
Please if anyone has any experience with it do let me know?? i have been stuck to it for few days now but cant find anything on the internet?

Comment: I suggest intercepting the screenshot event and canceling it rather than deleting the last photo.

Comment: Did you try this approach? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350145/circumvent-screenshot-for-ios-4

Comment: @hemant: Any luck achieving this with private api or any other tweak?